# Strange behaviour of binomial coefficient's delimiters

Tags: fonts, math-mode, amsmath, delimiters

> **This question led to a new package:**
>   [`fixcmex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fixcmex)

While writing down my Combinatorics exercises I found that the binomial coefficient's delimiters weren't displayed as indicated inside the `amsmath` documentation.

By subsequent trials and errors I was able to reduce the volume of my document to this simpler and fully compilable MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
%
\usepackage{amsmath}
%
\makeatletter
%
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%
\makeatother
%
\begin{document}
%
\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation}
2^k-\binom{k}{1}2^{k-1}+\binom{k}{2}2^{k-2}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[1]
%
\end{document}
```

Which gives (using TeXworks 0.44 on MikTeX 2.9.4521 updated 09/10/13) this un-expected result:

> [image]

While the `amsmath` doc shows that with the loaded packages inside the MWE the result would actually be like this:

> [image]

From here we can see that the delimiters on the first example are a little bit stretched vertically as they surpass the arguments inside the binom. coeff.

The more strange event is that when I comment the line `\usepackage{lmodern}` the result on delimiter's shape in my example looks exactly as the `amsmath` doc:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
%
\usepackage{amsmath}
%
\makeatletter
%
%\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%
\makeatother
%
\begin{document}
%
\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation}
2^k-\binom{k}{1}2^{k-1}+\binom{k}{2}2^{k-2}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[1]
%
\end{document}
```

Output:

> [image]

From here I deduce that the problem lies inside `lmodern`, but I'd like to keep using this package and fix this wierd "issue" with the math mode. Is there some clue that I've missed or this is in fact an update-process bug infecting `amsmath`'s delimiter control?

Comment: Just a note: you don't need `\makeatletter` `\makeatother` in this MWE.

Comment: @marczellm Yes, it works fluently both with and without those commands, as there is no `@` in between that needs to be activated...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is a problem in how `lmodern` sets up the math extensions font, by saying

```
\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{lmex}{m}{n}{%
   <->sfixed*lmex10%
   }{}
```

which is *utterly* wrong, in my opinion, because it destroys the settings made by `amsmath` which would solve the problem. The fonts, unfortunately, do not provide for optical sizes different from 10pt, so you have a few strategies

### 1. Use the `fixcmex` package

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{fixcmex}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation}
2^k-\binom{k}{1}2^{k-1}+\binom{k}{2}2^{k-2}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

*Disclaimer.* I authored the `fixcmex` package as a solution to the present problem.

### 2. Let `amsmath` do the main work

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbols}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n} % use cmex rather than lmex

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation}
2^k-\binom{k}{1}2^{k-1}+\binom{k}{2}2^{k-2}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

### 3. Load `exscale` or, better, the fonts defined by it

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}{%
      <-7.5> cmex7
      <7.5-8.5> cmex8
      <8.5-9.5> cmex9
      <9.5-> cmex10
       }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbols}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n} % use cmex rather than lmex

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation}
2^k-\binom{k}{1}2^{k-1}+\binom{k}{2}2^{k-2}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

### 4. Make `lmex10` scalable

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\DeclareFontFamily{OMX}{lmex}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{lmex}{m}{n}{%
   <-> lmex10
   }{}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation}
2^k-\binom{k}{1}2^{k-1}+\binom{k}{2}2^{k-2}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

With all strategies the computation for the delimiter's sizes gives a better result. Strategies two and three are rather similar; the difference is that the latter scales all fonts even at non standard sizes, while the former only uses fixed sizes 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 (10.95), 12, 14 (14.4) and 17 (17.28). Strategy one is equivalent to strategy three (and easier to load).

[image]

Comment: I honestly didn't come up with this strange issue in one and a half years of intense LaTeXing, but is it possible to a simple user like me to point this out to a mantainer?

Comment: @AndreaL. Probably you never used 11pt as base font size. Omit the fix and try `$A_{\sum}$` first without `lmodern` and then with it (load `amsmath` in both experiments). You'll have a surprise.

Comment: Thanks, I personally think that the second method shown in the answer is the most appropriate to my purposes. I'll think on the usage of `stackengine` (as given by @StevenB.Segletes) in addendum.

Comment: @campa Thanks, I fixed it.

Answer (score 6):

This answer relies on redefining `\binom` to use features of the `scalerel` and `stackengine` packages.  The `\scaleleftright` macro will make the paren delimiters exactly match the height of the binomial contents, which are stacked using `\stackanchor`.

The vertical gap between the components of the binomial coefficient is an optional argument to `\stackanchor` (currently set at 1.8ex), and the horizontal limiting width of the parens of the coefficient are given as an optional argument to `\scaleleftright` (currently set to 1.5ex).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{stackengine}
%
\makeatletter
%
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%
\makeatother
%
\begin{document}
%
\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation}
2^k-\binom{k}{1}2^{k-1}+\binom{k}{2}2^{k-2}
\end{equation}
\renewcommand\binom[2]{\stackMath\mathop{%
  \scaleleftright[1.5ex]{(}{\stackanchor[1.8ex]{#1}{#2}}{)}}}
\begin{equation}
2^k-\binom{k}{1}2^{k-1}+\binom{k}{2}2^{k-2}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[1]

%
\end{document}
```

The top image is the original that you posted, while the lower one is the fix proposed here.

[image]

Comment: Even though egreg made an answer that matched the delimiter size exactly with `amsmath` doc, I kind of like the vertical shrinking, just aligned at the base of the argument. Now I have two possibilities, which is great.

Comment: @AndreaL. Thanks.  The current MWE uses a "short" stack for the coefficient parts, wherein the gap is specified, and the stack is centered at the middle of the gap.  You may prefer a "long" stack wherein the inter-baseline distance is specified and the stack is centered halfway between the baselines.  To do that, `\renewcommand\binom[2]{\stackMath\def\stacktype{L}\mathop{%
  \scaleleftright[1.5ex]{(}{\stackanchor[1.1\baselineskip]{#1}{#2}}{)}}}` .  You'll see differences for short letters in the upper slot and/or descending letters in the lower slot.

Comment: @AndreaL.  As a follow up to prior comment, I should add that if differing heights/depths of indices over several terms within a single equation cause an odd look, a partial strut can be added in `\binom` before `#1` and `#2` in order to normalize the heights.

Comment: Well, thanks for the delucidation, the more tools and methods the more a knowledge is spread.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I am very happy with your answer, But, it does not sutiable with \usepackage{fouriernc}. Can you help me with when I add the command \usepackage{fouriernc}?

Comment: @minthao_2011 In my example, if I load `fouriernc` *before* I load the other packages, the `\scaleleftright` stuff seems to come out OK.  However, if I load the `fouriernc` stuff just before `\begin{document}`, then I have to reduce the maximum width setting for the `\scaleleftright`.  That is to say, I change the 1.5ex optional argument to, for example, 1ex.

Comment: Yuo try this line \[\dfrac{\binom{9}{6}}{x^2 + 5x + 2}\] and load `fouriernc` before I load the other packages.

Comment: @minthao_2011 Are you referring to the disappearance of the `+` signs in the denominator?  If so, this has nothing to do with my redefinition, but seems to arise from an interaction between the `fouriernc` and `lmodern` packages.  If you are referring to the fact that my `\binom` is always in the larger "display style", that is true.  I could try to develop a version for a smaller "text style" if that is what you refer to

Answer (score 0):

I add a similar problem as you recently, while using 11pt font size with the **lmodern** (*Latin Modern* font) package.  It never occured before (apparently) when I was using 10pt and 12pt font size.

A solution is to add a **nomath** option to the **lmodern** package, which will then use the *Latin Modern* for all the text, but will revert to AMS *Computer Modern* for the maths.  From OP's code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
%
\usepackage{amsmath}
%
\makeatletter
%
\usepackage[nomath]{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%
\makeatother
%
\begin{document}
%
\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation}
    2^k-\binom{k}{1}2^{k-1}+\binom{k}{2}2^{k-2}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[1]
%
\end{document}
```

This is the solution I use since a few days ago, until I find a better solution.  I don't see any major differences for the equations.