# Amsmath's \binom looking weird

Tags: amsmath, fontsize, koma-script

Using the MWE

```
\documentclass[fontsize=8pt, a4paper, DIV12]{scrbook}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[ e^t = x^{(5)} - 2x^{(3)} + \dot{x}
 = \sum_{k = 0}^{5} \binom{5}{k} p^{(k)}(t) e^t
 -2\sum_{k = 0}^{3} \binom{3}{k} p^{(k)}(t) e^t
 + \sum_{k = 0}^{1} \binom{1}{k} p^{(k)}(t) e^t
\]
\end{document}
```

I get the output

[image: Formula with strange looking binomial coefficients]

with strange looking binomial coefficients. Root cause is the font size.

Is there any way to get the usual look without changing font size?

Comment: What about using `\tbinom` instead of `\binom`?

Comment: I'm afraid not: it's an inherent problem with generalized fractions.

Comment: @Werner Noteworthy commands, but they yield the same result.

Comment: @arney: Surely they don't yield the same result... your reference to "strange looking" is subjective then.

Comment: trying this out with three different sizes -- nominal, `\small` and `\large` -- and also with `amsart` using the same three sizes, i see that with `scrbook`, the parentheses, except with `\large`, the parentheses fail to "cover" the contents.  using `amsart`, the parentheses are consistently tall enough to encompass both elements fully, and the result is much less objectionable.  i also tried it with the (not well known} 9pt option of `amsart`, and in that test, the parens on the `\small` instance are undersized.  so i think it's attributable to the size, as already suggested.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks for the indepth analysis. As I'm already over 150 pages, I'd rather not change font size now. As the strange look of the binomial gives it a clear visual distinction from 2D vectors (i.e. `pmatrix`), I might as well keep it.

Comment: Possibly related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137141/strange-behaviour-of-binomial-coefficients-delimiters

Comment: @arney Sorry for sounding harsh, but setting font size to 8pt isn't the way to reduce the number of pages. I know that this doesn't mean the "bug" in amsmath is not a bug, but you can't expect setting a ridiculous font size and expecting no problems of this type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the `\mbinom` command, from the `nccmath` package (medium-sized \binom, ~80 % of display style), it looks much better, in my opinion:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=8pt, a4paper, DIV12]{scrbook}

\usepackage{amsmath, nccmath}

\begin{document}

\[ e^t = x^{(5)} - 2x^{(3)} + \dot{x}
 = ∑_{k = 0}⁵ \mbinom{5}{k} p^{(k)}(t) e^t
 -2∑_{k = 0}³ \mbinom{3}{k} p^{(k)}(t) e^t
 + ∑_{k = 0}¹ \mbinom{1}{k} p^{(k)}(t) e^t
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, I don't like this. Either you keep the numbers full size, or you make them smaller and bring them closer...

Comment: @tohecz: That's a matter of personal taste. I don't like very much the sizing of `\tfrac` in a context of display style elements, as the difference is too big. My opinion is that 80 % of display style is a sensible compromise, but it's only my opinion…

Comment: There is a good reason why to have font sizes in discrete steps (usually `1.2` times), so that you clearly know of which font size is this or that part of the text or equation. So ok, you choose one step down for the binom, but then why the interline space that is almost one full baselineskip? And with `\frac` increasing the spacing is even worse, because you suddenly have the numerator and denominator floating in the middle of nowhere. But it's your choice to do that.

Comment: @tohecz: I usually have no change in \baselineskip because, as I also think the default is a little too tight compared to French usage, I use `\setstretch{1.05}` or so. But I do think it's a cultural habit.

Comment: Have to add my usual warning about `nccmath`: [Is there a replacement for nccmath?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22170/is-there-a-replacement-for-nccmath).

Comment: @Peter Grill: I remember we had a discussion about problems with nccmath (that I personally never had, but I have a sparse use of it). Also think I found a possible solution for it, from another thread, but I can't remember which it was. Did you keep some trace of this discussion?

Comment: @Bernard Sorry, the mentioning of baselineskip wasn't meant that way. I only wanted to say: You have the top and the bottom number miles away from each other. For no reason at all.

Comment: @Bernard: Sorry don't remember. As I had moved on from `nccmath` a long time ago I haven't really considered going back.

Comment: @Bernhard Thanks! I like that fontsize adjustment a lot. And since I avoid parboxes and minipages, I should be able to run it seamlessly.