# Inconsistent size of parentheses in Latin Modern and Computer Modern

Tags: delimiters, latin-modern, computer-modern

I have noticed that the sizes of delimiters change when I switch from Computer Modern to Latin Modern. In 12pt font size documents, this causes inline math with `\bigl(` to be too large to fit, and expands the vertical space taken by that line. This was not a problem with Computer Modern. Is this a bug?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
An equivalence class~$[a]_{\sim} \in A / {\sim}$ consists of all the elements
in $A$ that are mapped to $b = f(a)$. By the axiom of choice, there exists a
choice function~$c \colon A / {\sim} \to A$ which selects a representative
element of each equivalence class. There exists a
function~$h \colon B \to A / {\sim}$, so that
$h(b) = h\bigl(f(a)\bigr) = [a]_{\sim}$. This allows us to construct the
function~$g = c \circ h$, which is in fact a right-inverse of $f$.
\[
    \Biggl(\biggl(\Bigl(\bigl((X)\bigr)\Bigr)\biggr)\Biggr)
\]
\end{document}
```

**Computer Modern:**
[image: Computer Modern]

**Latin Modern:**
[image: Latin Modern]

There is a gap above the fourth line in the Latin Modern case, which is not there in the Computer Modern case.

---

### Edit:

[This post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/137143/15830) by egreg tackles the same problem.

Comment: I don't know if this is a bug, but a work-around consists in adding`\linespread{1.1}` to your preamble.

Comment: I can confirm that this inconsistency occurs if the main document font size is either `12pt` or `11pt`; interestingly, it is absent if the font size is `10pt`.

Comment: @egreg I added a link to a solution you wrote three years ago, which I think solves the problem.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For historical reasons a fixed size is used for the scalable delimiters, even for cm that's not clearly a good idea (see `exscale` package), but here it's not good at all, if you use the font at its natural scaled size then....

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\DeclareFontFamily{OMX}{lmex}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{lmex}{m}{n}{%
   <->lmex10%
   }{}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}



\show\big
\showthe\baselineskip
\setbox0\hbox{$\big($}\showthe\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0
\showoutput
\showbox0

An equivalence class~$[a]_{\sim} \in A / {\sim}$ consists of all the elements
in $A$ that are mapped to $b = f(a)$. By the axiom of choice, there exists a
choice function~$c \colon A / {\sim} \to A$ which selects a representative
element of each equivalence class. There exists a
function~$h \colon B \to A / {\sim}$, so that
$h(b) = h\bigl(f(a)\bigr) = [a]_{\sim}$. This allows us to construct the
function~$g = c \circ h$, which is in fact a right-inverse of $f$.
\[
    \Biggl(\biggl(\Bigl(\bigl((X)\bigr)\Bigr)\biggr)\Biggr)
\]
\end{document}
```

Now the size is shown as

```
> 14.5pt.
l.17 \showthe\baselineskip

? 

> 14.40013pt.
```

with `\big` just less than `\baselineskip`

---

You can redefine the `\big` size keeping it within `\baselineskip` and so avoid `\lineskip` glue being used within the paragraph.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}


\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\big}{\bBigg@{0.92}}
\makeatother
\show\big
\showthe\baselineskip
\setbox0\hbox{$\big($}\showthe\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0
\showoutput

An equivalence class~$[a]_{\sim} \in A / {\sim}$ consists of all the elements
in $A$ that are mapped to $b = f(a)$. By the axiom of choice, there exists a
choice function~$c \colon A / {\sim} \to A$ which selects a representative
element of each equivalence class. There exists a
function~$h \colon B \to A / {\sim}$, so that
$h(b) = h\bigl(f(a)\bigr) = [a]_{\sim}$. This allows us to construct the
function~$g = c \circ h$, which is in fact a right-inverse of $f$.
\[
    \Biggl(\biggl(\Bigl(\bigl((X)\bigr)\Bigr)\biggr)\Biggr)
\]
\end{document}
```

The `\show` at the top of the document show

```
> 14.5pt.
l.13 \showthe\baselineskip

? 

> 13.24792pt.
<to be read again>
```

showing that `\big(` is less than the 14.5pt baselinekip.

The .92 chosen empirically: .93 makes the font jump to the next available size, which is too big here.

Comment: This is an area where `amsmath` might do better: different fonts give different results, even missing some steps.

Comment: @egreg Michael wrote in the dtx: `%    The various kinds of struts could use some analysis and perhaps consolidation.` ....

Comment: It's a pity that the `NEXTLARGER` series cannot be accessed from within TeX.

Comment: @egreg a little luatex project for you....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle With your solution, `\big(` is the same size as just `(`. In Computer Modern, `\big(` seems to be of a size that is in-between what I get with `\big(` and `(` using Latin Modern. Is this size not available in Latin Modern?

Comment: @HåkonMarthinsen oh sorry I should have spotted that: you are doomed then....

Comment: @egreg ^^ any better ideas?

Comment: @HåkonMarthinsen ah no update coming up...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle If I understand this correctly then, it is actually Latin Modern that is scaling correctly here, and the `\big(` from Computer Modern is wrong? Maybe the ideal would be to have the CM-sized one in inline mode, and the LM-sized one in display mode.

Comment: @HåkonMarthinsen there are two kinds of scaling, the font itself has delimiters of various sizes and then "extendable" delimiter made out of bits and by default cm (and lm) use a fixed font size and just rely on the in-font delimiter sizing, alternatively you can scale the font as you would for a text font so use a 12pt font at 12pt and then use delimiter sizing within that as necessary. this gives far more control as you can use designed glyphs for sizes close to the font size, if you always use a fixed size font then for large font sizes, brackets switch sooner to teh "extendable" version

Comment: OK, so this seems to imply that Latin Modern contains delimiters of different sizes at 12pt, while Computer Modern does not, and substitutes the 10pt sized ones. Correct?

Comment: Not really, but it's hard to describe  but comments don't really work i had to truncate the last one to fit.

Answer (score 3):

You can solve your issue by forcing use of the `cmex` fonts. I will use the `exscale` like set-up from `amsfonts`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\DeclareFontFamily{OMX}{lmex}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{lmex}{m}{n}{%
       <-7.5>cmex7%
    <7.5-8.5>cmex8%
    <8.5-9.5>cmex9%
    <9.5->cmex10%
}{}%

\begin{document}

% \showoutput

An equivalence class~$[a]_{\sim} \in A / {\sim}$ consists of all the elements
in $A$ that are mapped to $b = f(a)$. By the axiom of choice, there exists a
choice function~$c \colon A / {\sim} \to A$ which selects a representative
element of each equivalence class. There exists a
function~$h \colon B \to A / {\sim}$, so that
$h(b) = h\bigl({f}(a)\bigr) = [a]_{\sim}$. This allows us to construct the
function~$g = c \circ h$, which is in fact a right-inverse of $f$.
\[
    \Biggl(\biggl(\Bigl(\bigl((X)\bigr)\Bigr)\biggr)\Biggr)
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I posted this without realizing an edit had been done to OP's with a link to egreg's http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/137143/4686 which contains (as second proposal) basically the same as I proposed here.