# Math operator not magnified in beamer frame

Tags: beamer, displaystyle, magnification

I would like to display a "big" formula in a beamer frame. If I test the `\Large` command this way

```
\documentclass[hyperref={colorlinks=true}]{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\uselanguage{Italian}
\languagepath{Italian}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,intersections,calc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test}
\[
f(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}c_ne^{inx}
\]

\Large
\[
f(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}c_ne^{inx}
\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

what I see is that the second formula is badly magnified: every symbol or letter is ok, but not the `\sum` operator, which remains small. What am I doing wrong?

This is what I see:

[image: Large command not working well]

Comment: I see a clear difference in size, please provide a full minimal example such that we can also see your preamble.

Comment: Are you perhaps loading `lmodern`?

Comment: Ok, I provided a working example and I am actually using lmodern. Thank you both.

Comment: Use the `fixcmex` package (cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/137141/14500 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/252354/14500).

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about this problem of lmodern package. Am I wrong using it?

Answer (score 1):

By using `\scalebox` or `\resizebox` from `graphicx` package, you can

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}% http;//ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\[
f(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}c_ne^{inx}
\]
\[
 \scalebox{2}{%
    $f(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}c_ne^{inx}$
}\]
\[
    \resizebox{3in}{0.5in}{%
        $f(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}c_ne^{inx}$
}\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

here `\scalebox{scale_factor}{content}` and `\resizebox{width}{height}{content}` this gives

[image]

Comment: I tried, but I wasn't able to use \scalebox in displaystyle math mode.